# iPhone orientation issue in single class

Tags: iphone, ios, screen, orientation, screen-orientation

i have 4 classes (class1, class2, class3 & class4) for class1, class2 & class3 i have all modes support (Landscape & Portrait). But for class 4 i need only Portrait support. Issue here is when i load class4 in Landscape mode its showing view in landscape, when i rotate class4 to Portrait mode once, its not rotating to landscape again. I want class4 to load in portrait only weather i come load class 4 in portrait or landscape mode.

```
i tried this
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   if (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
  {
     return NO;
  }
}
```

Please let me know, how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all you need to do is return a YES for everything but portrait orientation.

How about:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // b.t.w., there is also an upside down portrait constant
    // which is UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
    if (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
       return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

B.T.W., according to the public documentation for [`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a), this API is deprecated as of iOS 6.0.  If you care about your app's survivability for the future, you may want to consider doing something different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    -(void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)object{
        NSLog(@"orientation change");
        UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[object object] orientation];
        if(deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            Bg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"splashBgL.png"]; ///Lendscape Background
            Bg.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
            self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
        } 
        else{
            Bg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"splashBg.png"];///Protrait Background
            Bg.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        }
    }

    -(void)landscapeLeftOrientation{
          CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);;
          self.view.bounds = contentRect;
    }

    -(void)landscapeRightOrientation{
           CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
           self.view.bounds = contentRect;
    }


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
         [super viewDidLoad];
         [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
    }

    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
            [self landscapeLeftOrientation];
    }
```